# python perform an operation by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with 13 different brands (xx, yy, zz etc), all with 365 rows per brand (a full years worth of observations by brand). This is the result df.head().

```
           brand  exMarketplaces  incMarketplaces  availabilityRate    
date                                                                                                             
2015-08-01    xx      54372.8601     65826.384700          0.260209        
2015-08-02    xx      74335.6785     89722.492300          0.255547      
2015-08-03    xx      78563.0134    110132.200751          0.262365      
2015-08-04    xx      84414.0774    104982.190444          0.261942      
2015-08-05    xx      70499.8071     87368.524093          0.263748
```

I am trying to trim the outliers on a group level, based on the exMarketplaces column. The following code does so for the entire dataframe (regardless of brand).

```
df_clean = df[np.abs(df.exMarketplaces-df.exMarketplaces.mean())<=(3*df.exMarketplaces.std())]
```

However I would like to complete this operation on a brand level. So in effect, this operation should be run 13 times, for each of the 13 brands, and the result will be a single dataframe object with all outliers removed.

Can anybody suggest a way of doing this? I have the gut feeling it is quite a simple thing to do and that I am missing a trick here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform `Groupby` w.r.t the *brand* column and run the function on the column of interest using apply and finally take the filtered subset of the dataframe as shown:

```
func = lambda x: (np.abs(x-x.mean()) <= 3*x.std())
df_clean = df[df.groupby('brand')['exMarketplaces'].apply(func)]
```

Comment: The above works when I have a dataframe containing a single brand. When I do the same on a dataframe with mutliple brands, I get the following error - ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

Comment: Oh. Then you've got dates repeating in your index axis. Just perform `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` as a prior step.

Comment: I believe the issue is that date is set as the index. If I remove the index, then run the above, and re-index using date, the above works as intended :) edit - exactly as you said above. Thanks!